# "Can't Install {{App}}, try again and if still doesn't work, see common ways to fix the problem" Dialog from Google Play on Android 11 devices

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application on deployed on Google Play, and it's installable on devices, but when trying on devices with Android 11 system, it gives a dialog with this message "Can't Install {{App}}, try again and if still doesn't work, see common ways to fix the problem".
Event though the application is installable using APK file on the same device, but using Google Play it's not.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with some users from different devices. I think all this started several weeks ago when I decided to join the "app signing" feature in the Play Console. I don't remember exactly the name of that feature. But I would say it comes from that. I have contacted the Play Console team about this but they take too long to answer and normally ask for general things not related to the issue. Finally, my users get tired and stop using my app, so they stop answering my (Google's) requirements. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ive ended up solving my problem by removing this line of code on the manifest file:

```
android:protectionLevel="signature"
```